# Placing a textblock in WIndows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I am building an application in WIndows phone 7. I have the following xaml:

```
<Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="123" Margin="273,173,0,0"
Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20 />
```

Now here i want to insert a text and also make this clickable in order to navigate to a new page. How to do this. Please share some code

Comment: Hi, you want to insert text into rectangle, and navigate to other page when click the rectangle?

Comment: @ChrisShao Ya but i have done it in some other way

Comment: Yeah, it's good. Button can solve your question.

Comment: @ChrisShao Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299000/displaying-multiple-images-from-web-service-in-windows-phone-7-application?noredirect=1#comment33880480_22299000

Answer (score 0):

```
<Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="123" Margin="273,173,0,0"
 Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"
 MouseDown="SomeFunctionInCodeBehindToTakeYouToANewPage" />
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="340,222,0,0" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="I Like Pie" />
```